# jQuery Mobile ignoring data-role="none" on form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically injecting pages into my jQuery Mobile app.  Everything is working fine, except form elements.  It seems that data-role="none" is being ignored on form elements that are on the injected pages.

```
<p><input data-role='none' type='radio' name='type' id='type' value='none'/>None</p>
<p><input data-role='none' type='radio' name='type' id='type' value='segments'/>Market Segments</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp <select data-role='none' id='segments'><option value='all'>All</option></select></p>
```

The radio buttons render as regular radio buttons, albeit with some screwy formatting.  The select button should appear as a regular dropdown, but it is being rendered as a jQuery Mobile dropdown instead.

Here's how the pages are being injected:

```
var t = results.rows.item(i).body;
var n = results.rows.item(i).name;
$("#"+n).remove();
$("body").append(t);
$("#"+n).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
$("#"+n).attr('data-url',$("#"+n).attr("ID")).trigger('create');
```

Form elements on non-injected pages are working fine... any ideas?

Comment: It looks like rel='external' is broken on links as well after trigger('create') is called...

Answer (score 3):

By default jQuery Mobile will auto enhance form elements, if you want to tell JQM to [ignore](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html) them you can add the `data-role="none"` attribute to the container, however you also **need** to set `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true`. The reason for this is because by default JQM doesn't check for the `data-role="none"` attribute (so as to not perform a check every time needlessly).

Keep in mind that you need to set the `ignoreContentEnabled` in the [mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) `event`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are manually initialising those form controls. Since you are injecting those controls you may also be calling selectmenu('refresh') method. Just remove those calls and everything should work fine.