# Getting JSP Processing Error when using data-role="none" on form:radiobutton

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am a Front-end developer and facing issue with JSP page

The page is using jquery.mobile-1.2.0 and has a JSTL tag `form:radiobutton`, in order to avoid jquery mobile applying styles on this radio button, I added  `data-role="none"` on the tag and I am getting below error

> JSP Processing Error
> HTTP Error Code:   500

Below is what I see on console

> Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute data-role.

Anyone who has faced similar issue, can you tell me how to avoid styles getting applied to such radio buttons

Comment: Can you post your jsp page with relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're following points,

1. Add the `mobileinit` event with `ignoreContentEnabled : true` like this,

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
         $.extend( $.mobile , {
            ignoreContentEnabled : true
         });
      });
   </script>
   ```
2. The parent class (may be div) of the checkbox should have `data-enhance=false`. Because container should be `JQM widget`.

> If one is found the markup will be ignored. This setting and the
>   accompanying data attribute provide a mechanism through which users
>   can prevent enhancement over large sections of markup.

See references [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073309/jquery-mobile-ignoring-data-role-none-on-form-elements), [link2](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766378/jquery-mobile-data-role-none-not-working-sometimes). Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this already and no luck with this, I see no errors, will it work with jquery.mobile-1.2.0? because radio buttons are getting enhanced